# add onPress to first component and call it on second component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm a beginner in react-native I  want to make add ( + ) button on the header of the first component when user click on onPress it will create a new form and the form is the second component

[image: photo]

Answer (score 0):

In App.js SetUp Navigation like below:

```
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import MainScreen from "./screens/MainScreen";
import SecondScreen from "./screens/SecondScreen";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   MainScreen: {
  screen: MainScreen
},

SecondScreen: {
  screen: SecondScreen,
},
})

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

In Main Screen

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Button,
} from "react-native";

class MainScreen extends Component {

  handleOnPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("SecondScreen");
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
  onPress={this.handleOnPress}
  title="Button"
  color="#841584"
/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MainScreen;
```

It will redirect you to second screen

Comment: No I don't want like this bro, I have one screen which have parent component and also have child component i want redirect to next screen from child screen

Answer (score 0):

You can set ref of Form component

```
<FormsComponent
          ref={ref => {
            this.formComponent = ref;
          }}
        />
```

You should pass function as prop for Header component

```
<HeaderComponent addNewForm={this.addNewForm} />
```

Parent component will call function of form component when click in header component using ref

```
addNewForm = () => {
    this.formComponent.addNewForm();
  };
```

**App Preview**

[image]

**Complete Code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";

class HeaderComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 80, backgroundColor: "red", paddingTop: 24 }}>
        <Text style={{ padding: 20 }} onPress={this.props.addNewForm}>
          Call Function of Form Component
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class FormsComponent extends Component {
  addNewForm = () => {
    alert("add new form");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={[{ key: "Form1" }, { key: "Form2" }]}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  addNewForm = () => {
    this.formComponent.addNewForm();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <HeaderComponent addNewForm={this.addNewForm} />
        <FormsComponent
          ref={ref => {
            this.formComponent = ref;
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```